# bootstrap.yml file in src/main/resources and src/test/resources

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a bootstrap.yml file in src/main/resources that is enriched for various profiles. I have placed the same bootstrap.yml file in src/test/resources.

I would like my code to pick the bootstrap.yml file from src/test/resources when I run locally and the one in src/main/resources when run through a jenkins job. How to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to create a file bootstrap-local.yml then use the spring local profile once your running your app with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`. Resources under the test folder are placed there to be used in test classes.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this using 2 bootstrap files bootstrap-local.yml and bootstrap.yml in src/main/resources. Pass the command line argument **-Dspring.cloud.bootstrap.name=bootstrap-local** when you run your application or mvn test locally. If you don't pass this command line argument, by default it picks bootstrap.yml. In Jenkins, I don't provide this argument and it picks bootstrap.yml. Just in case if someone is in search of the same!